# Boot from Windows recovery image in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, windows-8.1, virtual-machine

I moved from Windows 8.1 to openSUSE a while ago. Before doing so I made a full system backup image using the native Windows utility for it. Ultimately it created, amongst other things, 3 vhdx files and I could see all my files on them in Windows after mounting them as drives. I was now wondering though if I could perhaps be able to create a VirtualBox VM from this recovery image and save the hassle of having to reinstall everything in the VM?

I could not find any info on how to do this but I mean there has to be a way for one to use such a recovery image to recover from i.e. a full drive failure and I think this should be technically similar or am I mistaken?

PS. Simply mounting the vhdx files in VB does not work, it complains about the format being to new or something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have vhdx files to test with, but these urls seem to have your problem solved:

http://key-value.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/mounting-vhd-image-file-in-linux.html

https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/using-libguestfs-to-read-hyper-v-vhdx-disk-images/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/295155/how-do-i-mount-vhd-file